# What is the purpose of "remove unused references"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compiler-construction, reference

I have read that removing unused references [makes no difference](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/10/20/245411.aspx) to the compiler as it ignores assemblies that are not being referenced in the code itself.

But I find it hard to believe because then, what is the real purpose of [Removing unused references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sfxafba.aspx)? It doesn't have any noticeable effect on the size of the generated assembly or otherwise. Or is this *smart* behaviour limited to the C# compiler (csc.exe) and not inherent to vbc.exe?

If this functionality is so useless, why does [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) offer it as a feature? Why is it provided within the Visual Studio Project Configuration dialog?

The only activity I can think of where this would be useful is during Deployment. References (used or unused) would still be copied by the installer. But for assemblies that reside in the GAC (for instance, BCL assemblies), this would not be a problem either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It prevents the CLR from loading the referenced module at runtime.  This will reduce startup time (since it takes time to load each module).   Depending on the size of the module it might noticeably reduce startup time.

One way to test this is to create a test WinForms project, add a reference to an assembly that isn't used (e.g., System.Web) then run and attach to the executable (e.g., F5).  View the loaded modules (Debug -> Windows -> Modules) and you'll see the referenced assembly was loaded.

If you think about it, it would be pretty hard for the CLR to determine whether or not a dependency (it's in the manifest as a dependency once you add a reference to it) is really used...  Especially since the execution of some code paths can't be known in advance...

Comment: How is the CLR going to load a module at runtime whose reference was removed by a compiler optimization? What am I missing here?

Comment: @Dan - I also don't understand why this answer got so many upvotes, from what I've read on other posts the compiler won't put the assembly reference in the final output if it's not used. The referenced assemblies will only be loaded by the JIT on the first call to a method of them. The loaded modules window that this answer brings as a proof might show all the references because it's on debug mode.

Comment: @BornToCode Also, if `it [is] hard for the CLR to determine whether or not a dependency is really used`, then how does "Remove unused references" work at all? Determining whether or not a reference is used is simple: if no code references anything in that assembly's namespace, then it is unused.

Answer (score 12):

Apart from the source files being smaller, I think it is just better to have a clean source file that has no unused code or references.

Comment: Thanks, Cristophe, but the question remains... how/why is it better?

Comment: It's better because your source files will not be bloated will unused code/imports and hence will be easier to read and understand. Additionally, I think that the compiler will have less work to do and compiling will be a tiny bit faster. (I'm not 100% sure about that and this is compiler specific)

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio 2008 also has the feature to remove unused using directives.

Removing unused code makes the code neater, but you can also reduce the risk of conflicts. Sometimes there are classes with the same name in different assemblies. For example, there is an `Image` class both in `System.Drawing` and `System.Web.UI.WebControls`. If you have using directives for both namespaces and start using the Image class, the compiler can't tell which of the ones to use.

Answer (score 7):

It is an optimization to make your project compile faster.  It avoids having the compiler load metadata that will never be used.  It's a minor one though, I'd guess at about 50 msec, depending on the speed of your hard drive and the file system cache state.

The C# compiler is smart enough to only emit .assembly references in the metadata of your compiled assembly for assemblies that are actually used.  So you won't generate native images for assemblies you don't use when you run Ngen.exe.  The JIT compiler won't be affected either way, it only loads assemblies as needed to translate the IL.

Comment: Does this imply that when a NGENed assembly is loaded all referenced assemblies are also loaded subsequently? Or in other words: Lazy loading of native assemblies is not possible? At least that's what I see when I compare the loaded assemblies of my application (JITed vs. NGENed).

Answer (score 1):

Reference Assistant for Visual Studio 2010 is the best tool for removing unused references in the application.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fc504cc6-5808-4da8-ae86-8d3f9ed81606